# extract data from xml subfields using python

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I have a xml file where I want to extract data from. I tried using python, but when I try to use an example script I found online, I can't extract the data I want.
I found a script at: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/parsing-xml-files-in-python-d7c136bb9aa5
it is able to extract the data from the given example, but when I try to apply this to my xml, I can't get it to work. Here is my xml file: https://pastebin.com/Q4HTYacM (it is ~200 lines long, which is why I pasted it to pastebin)

The Data I'm interested in can be found in the

```
<datafield  tag="100" ind1="1" ind2=" "> <!--VerfasserIn-->
   <subfield code="a">Ullenboom, Christian</subfield>
   <subfield code="e">VerfasserIn</subfield>
   <subfield code="0">(DE-588)123404738</subfield>
   <subfield code="0">(DE-627)502584122</subfield>
   <subfield code="0">(DE-576)184619254</subfield>
   <subfield code="4">aut</subfield>
</datafield>
```

Field, as well as some others. The problem is, that I'm interested in `<subfield code="a">Ullenboom, Christian</subfield>`
but I can't get it to extract, as it seems like the `root=tree.getroot()` only counts the first line as a searchable line and I haven't found any way to search for the specific datafields.

Any Help is appreciated.

Edit: My Script:

```py
## source: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/parsing-xml-files-in-python-d7c136bb9aa5

# import libs
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob

import xml.etree.cElementTree as et


#parse the file
tree=et.parse(glob.glob('./**/*baselinexml.xml',recursive=True)[0])

root=root.getroot()
#create list for values
creator = []
titlebook = []
VerfasserIn = []

# Converting the data
for creator in root.iter('datafield tag="100" '):
    print(creator)
print("step1")
creator.append(VerfasserIn)
for titlebook in root.iter('datafield tag="245" ind1="1" ind2="0"'):
    print(titlebook.text)


# creating dataframe

Jobs_df = pd.DataFrame(
list(zip(creator, titlebook)),
columns=['creator','titlebook'])
#saving as .csv

Jobs_df.to_csv("sample-api1.csv")
```

I'm fairly new to this kind of programming, so I tried modifying the code from the example

Comment: Please include in the question your version of the script, as the one in the*URL* deals with a different *XML* tree.

Comment: @CristiFati I added my poor attempt of a script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: xml.etree.ElementTree - The ElementTree XML API](https://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree), you will find everything you need to know there.

The *XML* you posted on *PasteBin* is not complete (and therefore invalid). It's lacking `</zs:recordData></zs:record></zs:records></zs:searchRetrieveResponse>` at the end.

The presence of namespaces makes things complicated, as the (real) node tags are not the literal strings from the file. You should insist on namespaces, and also on *XPath* in the above *URL*.

Here's a variant.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET


def main(*argv):
    doc = ET.parse("./blob.xml")  # Saved (and corrected) the file from PasteBin
    root = doc.getroot()
    namespaces = {  # Manually extracted from the XML file, but there could be code written to automatically do that.
        "zs": "http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/",
        "": "http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim",
    }
    #print(root)
    datafield_nodes_path = "./zs:records/zs:record/zs:recordData/record/datafield"  # XPath
    datafield_attribute_filters = [
        {
            "tag": "100",
            "ind1": "1",
            "ind2": " ",
        },
        {
            "tag": "245",
            "ind1": "1",
            "ind2": "0",
        },
    ]
    #datafield_attribute_filters = []  # Decomment this line to clear filters (and process each datafield node)
    ret = []
    for datafield_node in root.iterfind(datafield_nodes_path, namespaces=namespaces):
        if datafield_attribute_filters:
            skip_node = True
            for attr_dict in datafield_attribute_filters:
                for k, v in attr_dict.items():
                    if datafield_node.get(k) != v:
                        break
                else:
                    skip_node = False
                    break
            if skip_node:
                continue
        for subfield_node in datafield_node.iterfind("./subfield[@code='a']", namespaces=namespaces):
            ret.append(subfield_node.text)
    print("Results:")
    for i, e in enumerate(ret, start=1):
        print("{:2d}: {:s}".format(i, e))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q071724477]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Results:
>  1: Ullenboom, Christian
>  2: Java ist auch eine Insel
>
> Done.
> ```

In the above example, I extracted the text of every *subfield* node (with *code* attribute having a value of ***a***) which is a child of a *datafield* node **that has the attributes matching one of the entries in the *datafield_attribute_filters* list** (got the attributes filtering later, from your script). 
You can do some more filtering if you need to.

Comment: Thanks for the provided Code.
I'll give it a go and see if everything works and if I have to add some additional filters